# oven repair, is it possible the gas line is clogged?

Tags: oven, natural-gas

Mistaking a broiler for a storage drawer below the oven, my friend placed a single medium size piece of tupperware inside the broiler.  Naturally it was lit on fire, and a lot of soot (and fire extinguisher chemicals) were deposited on and around the igniter.  The igniter still glows hot when the oven is turned on, but I don't hear gas and it doesn't ignite.
Should I suspect the heating element is too dirty to work effectively?
That the gas line has become clogged? 
Could cleaning some of these parts help or do they probably need to be replaced?

The oven/stove is a GE model JGBS22BEA1WH

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning is always a good idea after a mishap like this, but if it does not immediately fix the problem, you should call in a professional repair service. A fire in an appliance, especially a gas fed appliance, needs a pro to ensure that the unit is still safe to operate.

Many plastics can form a pretty solid mess when melted onto metal. It may be difficult or prohibitive in time to clean some of those parts. Also, the burning plastic may have damaged a thermostat or electrical connects. Whether anything needs to be replaced is again a decision that should be made by a professional specifically familiar with this unit and who can directly inspect the damage (or lack of damage).

Answer (score 2):

Gads, what a mess that must have been!

Cleaning the igniter and flame sensor certainly could not make the situation worse—well, unless it is done with brutal force.

Also, check the alignment of the igniter.  Perhaps it shifted during whatever was done during the fire.

It is also likely some of the gas burner holes are clogged.  Inspect carefully and clean those.

While I understand naysayers who say "call a professional", this is not rocket science.  But do use due caution when test firing after working on it.  If gas starts to flow before the igniter is good and bright, turn off the broiler immediately and ventilate before going near it again.